# Warnings in dartium when using some paper/core elements

Tags: dart, dart-polymer

I'm trying to use paper-tabs, paper-tab and core-pages elements but dartium shows a bunch of warnings like:

```
(from html5lib) Unexpected non-space characters. Expected DOCTYPE. 
package:paper_elements/paper_tabs.dart:1:1

(from html5lib) Unexpected character after attribute value. 
package:paper_elements/paper_tabs.dart:38:9
```

And then:

```
custom element with name "paper-tabs" not found.
```

As you may guess these elements doesn't work. Other elements like core-overlay, core-field, paper-button seems to work fine. I'm using dart 1.9.0-dev.3.0, core_elements 0.6.0+5, paper_elements 0.6.1 and polymer 0.15.5+4. What may be the cause of such behaviour?

Comment: Have you tried `pub cache repair` (on command line) maybe some files are corrupted.

Comment: Yes, I have tried it several times.

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: The code is not public, but I will try to make some small example to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Here is small example: [github](https://github.com/slodko/dart_test2). I know I messed up something with packages structure (which is really easy to do because warnings from sdk doesn't help, also ide - eclipse plugin - is not helpful. It's sad that so great language is still so difficult to use).

Comment: Seems to be this bug https://github.com/dart-lang/core-elements/issues/117 but seems to have become worse. It looks like the HTML in the comments is analyzed and leads to errors. I'll ping the issue and see what they tell. Despite the warnings everthing seems to work fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused by some html imports pointing to dart files instead of html files inside of foo_element.html ([code here](https://github.com/slodko/dart_test2/blob/master/lib/foo_element/foo_element.html#L2)). Swapping those imports to point to html files removes all warnings.