# Exception calling initPolymer() in dartiums device mode

Tags: dart, dart-polymer, dartium

I have simple dart polymer app: [git repository](https://github.com/slodko/dart_test2). When I run it in dartiums 'device mode' (selected device: Nexus 5) `initPolymer()` throws exception:

```
Exception: Already registered (Polymer) prototype for element auto-binding-dart
```

The same code works fine when 'device mode' is turned off (although there are some warninings, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28841089/warnings-in-dartium-when-using-some-paper-core-elements)). I have used polymer 0.15.5+4. Any ideas how to fix it?

Comment: It's weird, you are not even using this element. All your code seems fine.  Please create a bug report at http://dartbug.com

Comment: Bug report: [dartbug.com](https://code.google.com/p/dart/issues/detail?id=22716&thanks=22716&ts=1425736434)

Comment: Have you tried not to use a custom main method? (using ` <script type="application/dart">export 'package:polymer/init.dart';</script>` as script tag in your `index.html`?