# Dart Polymer: binding html files to scripts results in broken bootstrap.dart containing "%5C" characters

Tags: dart, polymer, smoke

After doing a Pub Get and Pub Upgrade my custom-PolymerElements don't work anymore. It seems to me that the

```
<script type="application/dart" src="view.dart"></script>
```

is interpreted incorrectly. In my index.html_bootstrap.dart it is listed as: `import 'dialog%5Cview.dart' as smoke_1;` The "%5C" ( \ ) should be a slash ( / ) anyway and I'm pretty sure that it shouldn't be escaped. I tried it with the dart stable (1.8.5) and dev (1.9.0) versions for 64bit Windows.

I already tried to revert my package to their previous version but since I hadn't constraint them in my pubspec file I have no way to determine which versions worked before my changes. In another dart polymer project I'm working on I use the same setup (extended polymer elements) and it still works . The equivalent position in the index.html_bootstrap.dart reads: `import 'dialog/view.dart' as smoke_1;`

(edit) some (shortened) code:

/web/dialog/error/view.html

```
<link rel="import" href="packages/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="packages/paper_elements/paper_dialog.html">
<link rel="import" href="packages/core_elements/core_animated_pages.html">

<polymer-element name="error-view">
<template>
    <style>
        paper-dialog {
            margin-top: 20px;
            height: 400px;
            width: 600px; }     
    </style>
    <paper-dialog id="extendedNode" heading="{{dialogtitle}}" vertical autoCloseDisabled=true transition="paper-transition-center" opened=true>
      <content> 
      <core-animated-pages selected="{{page}}" valueattr="id" transitions="hero-transition cross-fade">
            <section id="0">
                    <p  cross-fade>A system error occured while connecting with the server.</p>
                    <br>
                    <p  cross-fade>Error message: {{dialogtext}}</p>
          </section>       
    </core-animated-pages>
    </content>
    </paper-dialog>
  </template>

<script type="application/dart" src="view.dart"></script>
</polymer-element>
```

/web/dialog/error/view.dart

```
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import '../view.dart'; // <- the base class 'DialogView'

  @CustomTag('error-view')
  class ErrorView extends DialogView{

    ErrorView.created() : super.created(){
    componentName = 'error-view';
    this.dialogtitle = 'System Error';
  }

}
```

/web/dialog/view.dart

```
import 'package:polymer/polymer.dart';
import 'dart:html';
import 'package:intl/intl.dart';

import '../locale/de.dart' as de;

class DialogView extends PolymerElement {
   @observable int page;
   //there are a lot of helper functions and variables in here
}
```

I use many pairs of those components extending the base component (which has no view.html but only a view.dart that allows me to hold and manipulate different dialogs within one List. This worked perfectly fine until I did the Pub Get / Upgrade and was not solved by repairing the cache. A project using a similar structure still works fine.

Comment: If it started after `pub upgrade` try to run `pub cache repair` from the command line. Ensure you didn't do as described in this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28841089.

Comment: A 'pub cache repair' did not resolve the problem. The answer of your linked question seems to be about linking from the html view of polymer elements to dart files, which I don't do - except at the end to its 'controller'. I will update my question to show some code.

Comment: Do you get any errors/warnings when you run it in Dartium with pub serve (launch from DartEditor)?

Comment: Building it with pub serve does not generate any warnings and completes successfully. Shortly after that I get `[web] GET /dialog%5Cview.dart => Could not find asset symconf|web/dialog%5Cview.dart.`in Tools Output and it's equivalent in index.html `Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
  http://localhost:8080/dialog%5Cview.dart`

Comment: I have no idea, consider creating a bug report at http://dartbug.com

Comment: Thanks for trying anyway! I will try to reproduce and then report the bug.

Comment: Have you enabled analysis server recently in DartEditor settings? I saw a bug report recently that files are not found in webapps launched from DartEditor when Analysis server is enabled.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This resolves it for now:

pubspec.yaml

code_transformers: '<= 0.2.5'

Comment: Did you create a bug report?

Comment: Thank you! This fixes the problem I encountered.